# OSX 10.4.11 Intel Macbook pro

Tags: macos

I am using Camino on OSX 10.4.11, this combination still works well.  I am able to use yahoo mail and youtube.  I get constant requests to update Flash player.  There does not appear to be an appropriate iteration at the download site.  This primarily affects my ability to use the BBC site.  Are there any alternatives without upgrading at this time since the MacBookPro I am using performs well.  I am very fond of the esthetics of this OS and have had only rare problems in 8 years of near constant use.  Can you make helpful suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Could you elaborate on what specifically you request guidance. [ask] should help guide your editing.

Answer (score 2):

Camino is dead.

[Camino Browser](http://caminobrowser.org)

Since it is dead, there will be nobody developing anything for it - it simply doesn't make sense.

I do have to ask...why are you not using at least OS X 10.8?  What Intel MBP are you using that doesn't' support this version?

The bottom line is that you will need to upgrade.  Flash is a huge security hole in and of itself and everyone is moving to HTML5/CSS3 compliant browsers.  You are going to soon find that you can no longer reliably browse the web.

Comment: Maybe OP doesn't want to pay for Snow Leopard, the prerequisite for any of the now-free updates that followed it.

Comment: I hope that's not the case.  I bought an original CD from Apple for $20 or so.  A quick search on Amazon and they are selling for $28.  Small price to pay IMO.